# Render django template as html file

Tags: html, django-templates

I need to move a django project to to a php server, and i want to keep as much of the front-end as possible. 
Is there an easy way to render the templates into un-tagged HTML files and deposit them into a "template_root" as with static and media files?

Or at least have a view do the render on page load and save the resulting html to a file?  (just for dev!)

i'm not concerned about the dynamic data from the views, just don't want to rewrite all the "extends" and "includes" and "staticfiles" or custom template tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a way to do this on a per View bases, using Django's render_to_string:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings

def homepage(request):
    context = {}
    template_name = "main/homepage.html"
    if settings.DEBUG == True:
        if "/" in template_name and template_name.endswith('.html'):
            filename = template_name[(template_name.find("/")+1):len(template_name)-len(".html")] + "_flat.html"
        elif template_name.endswith('.html'):
            filename = template_name[:len(template_name)-len(".html")] + "_flat.html"
        else:
            raise ValueError("The template name could not be parsed or is in a subfolder")
        #print(filename)
        html_string = render_to_string(template_name, context)
        #print(html_string)
        filepath = "../templates_cdn/" + filename
        print(filepath)
        f = open(filepath, 'w+')
        f.write(html_string)
        f.close()
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

I tried making it as generic as possible, so i can add it to any view. 
I've used it to write a view that calls all templates iteratively and converts them all too, so is closer to "collectstatic" functionality

I don't know how to get the template_name from the render args, so i can just make it a function to re-use. Might be easier as a class-based-view mixin?